# Spring boot App - while running Cucumber executable jar from command prompt getting scenario and steps undefined

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, automation-testing

using maven-assembly-plugin able to generate cucumber excitable jar for Spring boot Application. But while running cucumber excitable jar from command prompt it showing scenario and steps undefined.

Undefined scenarios:
....

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (3 skipped, 1 undefined)
0m1.585s

pom.xml maven-assembly-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.test.CucumberRunner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

assembly.xml:

```
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>fat-tests</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```